# specify the default color for calendar event

Tags: calendar, sharepoint-calendar

When I add a calendar to my SharePoint site the default color for events is black (except for one subsite, which defaults to the standard blue). I don't like the black and I was wondering how you change the default color for a calendar. I'm not looking to overlay calendars or have different colors for different event types, I just want to be able to specify the default color for the calendar to be something other than black.

Also, if anyone has any ideas as to why one random subsite *does* have a standard blue color, I am curious about that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In context of your comment on the above answer It seems that you want to change the color of calendar event without changing the theme. I am having an approach for you. As I achieved it near past when I was having requirement to change the color of Calendar based on the event category.

What I did was,

- I edited the page on which calendar view was placed.
- Kept a Content Editor WebPart
- Added following code into it.

  ```
  $(".ms-acal-item").css("background-color", "orange"); // You can use any color you want
  ```
- Save the page.

By doing this my calendar looked like

[image: My Calendar]

I know this is not the ultimate solution. But I guess it may help you to achieve what you want to achieve.

Let me know whether you need some more assist on this.

Answer (score 4):

The calendar colors are based on your sites style/theme. So my guess is that you are using a non default theme (or perhaps you created your own) on the sites that are showing black, and the default one on the one that shows blue. If you click the gear in the top corner, then click change the look, you'll see the color palette for each theme. Typically the color used as Accent 1 will be your default new event color.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the accent colors of a theme without changing the theme? I'm managing the site now but I didn't build it, so I don't want to mess something up by changing the theme

Answer (score 0):

This is PERFECT!  Since we are using color-coded events in Outlook, the same colors are propagated on our SharePoint calendar (on the SharePoint site).  I needed to change the default color to RED to show if an event is missing the category (we did not want to make category a required field since the new item is enter in Outlook).  At a glance the user can see if an event has not been categorized. I added an email workflow to notify the person creating the event, to update with a category.