# Calendar Overlay: change the "Calendar in View" section to match CSS coding colors

Tags: css, calendar, overlay

I was tasked to make a district vacation calendar that each department can manage. They wanted to see an overview of everyone but also have the ability to "drill down" into their own groups. I wasn't sure the best way so I created a calendar for each group and created a District calendar to overlay of all of them in for the overview.

The District Calendar will always be overlayed into the group calendars as it holds key events that pertain to all groups.

What I would like to do is have the color coding from the overlay carry over when drilling into the group view. I.e. all Administration entries are in green.

I followed the instructions from this post ([Calendar Color-Coding](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/188558/calendar-color-coding)) and managed get it to work within the calendar but I was hoping the colors would carry over to the legend part under the "Calendars in View" on the left. Is this possible?